# How to sort flatlist in React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist

I have data stored in a state that is shown in flatlist, I want to sort the data based on ratings. So if I click on sort button they should be sorted in `ascending` order and when I click again, they should be sorted in `descending` order.

I have an array of objects stored in state, below is just a piece of data that is important.

```
show_data_list = [{ ratings : { overall : 4, ...other stuff } } ]
```

Is there a way I could do it, I tried using the map function which sorts array

```
list.map((a,b) => a-b)
```

But how can I use this to sort my array of objects, I cant pass in 2 `item.rating.overall` as the parameter.

Thanks in advance for the help :)

Comment: Would be easier to help if you provided a bit more information regarding your data structure. However, this is a good resource regarding sorting arrays in js: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `javascript`'s built in `sort` function. You can provide a custom `comparer` function for it, which should return a negative value if the first item takes precedence, 0 if they are the same and a positive value if the second value should take precedence.

`show_data_list.sort((a, b) => { return a.ratings.overall - b.ratings.overall; })`. This will sort the data in the ascending order.

`show_data_list.sort((a, b) => { return b.ratings.overall - a.ratings.overall; })`. This will sort it in the descending order.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I solved it stored the data in a variable and then sorted it based on condition

```
let rating = this.state.show_data_list;
      rating.sort(function(a,b) {
        return a.ratings.Overall < b.ratings.Overall
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try This**

Sort your List Ascending/ Descending order with name or other string value in list

> const [productSortList, setProductSortList] = useState(productarray);

where **productarray** is your main array

**Ascending**

```
productarray.sort((a, b) => a.products_name < b.products_name)
```

**Descending**

```
productarray.sort((a, b) => b.products_name < a.products_name),
```

You can reset the **state** of array you have passed as data in **Flatlist**

```
ascending ->   

setProductSortList(
   productarray.sort((a, b) => a.products_name < b.products_name),
);
```

do same for descending