# Sorting React-native FlatList Alphabatically

Tags: reactjs, react-native

This is the array from which flat lis is getting data

```
const DATA = [
{
  id: '1',
  name: 'Hamza Ahzam',
  phone: '03076232309',
  DOB: '05/07/96',
},
{
  id: '2',
  name: 'Ahzam',
  phone: '03156232323',
  DOB: '05/07/9',


},
{
  id: '3',
  name: 'Usman Ahmad Raza',
  phone: '03016232376',
  DOB: '05/07/99',

},
```

];

This is the Code in which Flat list is displaying only name data I Want to sort the names according to alphabates can any 1 help

```
const Details = ({navigation,name}) => {
const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <Item name={item.name}  />
  ); 
 const Item = ({ name }) => (
 <View style={styles.item}>
 <Text style={styles.name}>{name}</Text>
   </View>
  );
return (
<SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
  <FlatList
    data={DATA}
    renderItem={renderItem}
    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
  />
</SafeAreaView>
);
```

Comment: Check out this post [How to Sort FlatList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60621248/how-to-sort-flatlist-in-react-native) hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you case `sort` method can be useful to name sorting. Try following example,

```
  <FlatList
   data={DATA.sort(function(a, b) {
    return (a.name < b.name) ? -1 : (a.name > b.name) ? 1 : 0;
   })
  }
```

It will be sort of your object array according to name property.

Hope it works.